# How to add a conditional to call the second fetch if the first fetch call returns no data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make 2 fetch calls. The first fetch call checks for the data in the local database. If the data is there then update the state. If the data is not there then the second fetch call needs to be make which goes to the external api to retrieve the information. If it's find the data, then update the state.

If the data is not found in either of the fetch calls then the message needs to be display to the user that "No records found. Please add a record manually."

So far, this is what I have in a component:

```
this.state = {
  data: []
};

search = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  fetch(`url1`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        data: response
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  fetch(`url2`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        data: response
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

render() {
  return(
    <button name="record" onClick={this.search}>Search Record</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: if empty, return fetch2();. chain as normal.

Comment: before doing a second fetch call, I added a conditional like so `if(this.state.data.length === 0)` then do the second fetch call, but if my first call succeed and get the data then the second call is always getting called. Is there a way to prevent the fetch from calling if one the other one is successfull?

Comment: That won't work, the state doesn't get updated till some time in the future. The logic needs to be in the callback of the first fetch.

Comment: I am not really sure how to achieve that. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the response within the asynchronous call chain before setting state and fire the other fetch (or any promise) if the response length is zero. Quite conveniently, the fired fetch will get chained to the rest of the call backs you specified for the first promise.

```
search = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  }

  fetch(`url1`, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => response.length > 0 
                    ? response 
                    : fetch(`url2`, options).then(response => response.json()))
  .then(response => this.setState({ data: response }))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function for the fallback fetch, then call it in the first fetch, upon receiving no data.

```
this.state = {
  data: []
};

search = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const fetch2 = () => {
    fetch(`url2`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  fetch(`url1`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      if (response) { // however you need to check for valid response
        this.setState({
          data: response
        });
      } else {
        fetch2();
      }

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });


};

render() {
  return ( <
    button name = "record"
    onClick = {
      this.search
    } > Search Record < /button>
  )
}
```